Autodesk Construction Cloud API: Looking for the viewableGuid of the most recent fileversion of a view
I have a piece of python code using the Autodesk Construction Cloud Issues API as such:
get_issues_url = f"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/issues/v1/projects/{self.PROJECT_ID}/issues"
headers = {
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.ACCESS_TOKEN}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

From the response I am able to get all kinds of properties for each issue. One of these is a viewableGuid which can be found at: response > results > linkedDocuments > details > viewable > guid.
The viewableGuid is the guid of the individual viewable associated with the issue (pushpin). Read: it is the guid associated with a specific page in a PDF or view/sheet in a model, etc... on which an issue locating pushpin is placed/located.
This is all according to the API reference documentation that can be found here.
IMPORTANT: I am working with files (models, single and multi-page PDF's, ...) in the Project Files folder in Docs on the Autodesk Construction Cloud, not with Sheets in the Build module or something else.
My code runs fine. However, I have found out that the viewable guid associated with the issue is the guid of the view that was available in the file version in which the issue was created. (At the moment of creation presumeably the latest file version at that time.) The version of the file at the moment of creation of the issue is BTW specifically mentioned under the property 'createdAtVersion', found here: response > results > linkedDocuments > createdAtVersion.
Now comes the problem: When, after creation of an issue, the issue-carrying file gets updated with a new version, all guids of the viewables (pages/views/sheets) inside change, making it so that the found viewableGuid via the Issues API request will not match with the viewableGuids in the current and most recent fileversion. This makes it then impossible to construct a hyperlink to this issue, which I would like to present to a user from a Power BI Dashboard for example. The strange thing is that if I use the Autodesk Construction Cloud webinterface to manually browse to the issue via the Issue Management user interface and when I inspect the link element presented over there it definitely links properly to the latest file version and makes use of an updated viewableGuid.
In short: My problem is that the Autodesk webinterface clearly is able to present an updated search link to the issue and use this in the webinterface, but that this updated search link is not retrieveable via the API, which is a pity.
I hope I am overlooking something, so if there is anyone who is able to show me my fault or point me towards a solution I would be most grateful. Many thanks for your time and consideration.
Kind regards
Paulus
PS: I have already considered listing all the files (most recent version) on the project and getting all the viewableGuids inside and matching them by name to the outdated ones found via the Issues API, but I can't seem to find an API which is able to straightup list the viewables inside a file. There is a Sheets API that does this for Sheets in the Build module, but as stated above, I am not working with the Build module and Sheets, but with Project Files in the Docs module.
